# How to add new fields on document on ingestion based on value of other fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scenario where different applications are sending different fields for the same purpose which is making getting the aggregates/query data difficult and resulting in Big query.

Here is one of the fields which specify the file path.

For example:

App1 is sending "FilePath" as the file path.
App2 is Sending "CurrentFilePath" as the file path.
App3 is Sending "ItemPath" as the file path

As you can see the above Apps are sending 3 different fields for the file path. Is there a way I can populate an extra field "FilePath" for App2 and App3 documents on ingestion, so that single query on-field "FilePath" work for getting data as well as aggregates.

NOTE: When I search for documents with field "FilePath", I want to get the complete document with all properties including "FilePath" for all the apps.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rename preprocessor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rename-processor.html) to change name of existing field.

{
  "rename": {
    "field": "source_field_name",
    "target_field": "target_field_name"
  }